# IAM users access to Amazon Redshift serverless

Tags: amazon-redshift-serverless

I'm trying to grant iam users to view redshift serverless but I get this errors when view the redshift page with my iam users:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/milad is not authorized to perform: redshift-serverless:ListSnapshots because no identity-based policy allows the redshift-serverless:ListSnapshots action
User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/milad is not authorized to perform: redshift-serverless:DescribeConfiguration because no identity-based policy allows the redshift-serverless:DescribeConfiguration action
User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:user/milad is not authorized to perform: redshift-serverless:GetCredentials because no identity-based policy allows the redshift-serverless:GetCredentials action
```

However I can't create a policy like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "redshift-serverless:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Because `redshift-serverless` is an invalid action. I couldn't figure out what is the valid action for redshift serverless.

If I replace Action to `"Action": "*"` my users get access but ofc I won't want to grant them full access!

I did find [Redshift serverless security doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-security.html) but didn't really understand it

Answer (score 1):

I think that your policy might be correct, just create it and use it.

IAM might be throwing this error which in does in my case:

> redshift-serverless: IAM does not recognize this service. The service might include a typo or might be a previewed or custom service.

As Redshift serverless is still in preview, it is not yet recognized by iam, don't be thrown off by IAM not recognizing the service.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_policies.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#troubleshoot_policies-unrecognized-visual

> Preview service – Services that are in preview do not support the visual editor. If you are participating in the preview, you can ignore the warning and continue, though you must manually type the actions and resource ARNs to complete your policy. Alternatively, you can choose the JSON tab to type or paste a JSON policy document.